# Authorization on website in PERL

Tags: perl, web

How to open website on Internet browser (i.e. Firefox) with authorization in Perl?

In example?

```
my $url = "http://www.google.com/";
system(qq{start "" "$url"});
```

Above code opens website www.google.com, but how to open it when website requires authorization?

Comment: i'm afraid this question is not related to perl, but to windows. using start url  seems ignores credentials in url in user:pass@ format. From the perl's perspective you are doing everything right. Just try to achieve what you want from cmd and then put it to system call

Comment: Referring to to Perl maybe there is any method providing such functionality?

Comment: Perl is just proxy here. Let's say: it's just typing it in cmd instead of you. You could try to investigate different browsers approach, may be they have special cmd line options to pass credentials. As far as I understand the process, there is no simple over table approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) module, which allows you to control Firefox browser with Perl.

The documentation is quite good, and there are a lot of methods, so you should be able to find what you want by yourself on the CPAN documentation.

I've never used it on Windows, but I think it should work fine. (It's based on Firefox Mozrepl module, which works on Windows)